# Enable a javascript plugin on button press

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage on which there a button.
 
On button press, I intent to embed a script in the `head` section of the page to enable a plugin. I can manually insert the snippet and my plugin but I want to be able to do this on button click itself to keep it as an optional element for my users.
What is the way to go about this?

As per `@padde`'s query, the script looks like the following the way I include in my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.abc.com/farfalla.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.abc.com/postmessage.js"></script>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the script into your question. Then, i could give a more precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would simply put the script inside the `<head>` tags. Then, extract the initializing code from the included script and run it when the button was clicked.

**Edit**

You can also try this:

HTML

```
<button id="share-button">Share this</button>
```

​
JavaScript

```
dynamicCode = 'alert("script loaded");'
scriptLoaded = false;

buttonClicked = function(e) {
    if( !scriptLoaded ) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.text = dynamicCode;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        scriptLoaded = true;
    }

    alert("thanks for sharing");
};

button = document.getElementById('share-button');
button.onclick=buttonClicked;
```

​

where you would load the `dynamicCode` with an Ajax call or whatever you like. The code is only loaded once. I've put together a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5EWhK/) for you, so you can try it out.

Comment: This bit is something different. I am trying to build this as a third party 'share' like button, which can be placed on any website and it starts working. It would be a hassle to ask each website who opts this to add the scripts to their page and keep a button to initialize the code from there.

Comment: Do not assign to the script element's innerHTML (script elements don't have any internal markup). Assign instead to the text property.

Comment: @user1372448 If you want a widget, it requires a script tag. And imho this answer is sufficient enough.

Comment: @padde thanks for the clarification. Well, I guess that button could look like a widget e.g. `<div class="addthis_toolbox"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.addthis.com/js/addthis_widget.js#...."></script>` (And also I am sorry for my amateurish speaking in English.)

Answer (score 0):

Use createElement() of javascript and add it to the DOM

Check the below link for more information : http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Howto_Dynamically_Insert_Javascript_And_CSS

If you are using jquery then you can use $.getScript to load the external js file.

```
$.getScript('filename.js',function(){
 //your code ...
});
```